# One-Third /Two-Third layout with images

Tags: html, css, image, zurb-foundation

I am a newbie to this - so here is my problem:

I'm trying to make a one-third / two-third layout with foundation 4.0.8. (the whole thing needs to be responsive)
On mobile it should like this: 1 image - 2 small image - 1 image.

Desktop Layout:

[image]

My approach so far: make divs with the right grid settings -> insert a second div with a large-12 grid and inside of it is the image.

So far so good, but now I struggle with the images: The large-4 div has not the same height as the other one. :(

Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
      <div class="large-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      <div class="large-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      <div class="large-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
      <div class="large-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which grid system are you using?

Comment: One of the tag says "foundation" so I am guessing the OP meant to use Zurb Foundation.

Comment: Zurb Foundation. Sorry - forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the actual content of each grid element controls the height and width (content area). To see what I mean replace each of your `img` element with a `panel` and write some varying texts. You will see that each panel is of different heights. Here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
          <div class="large-12">
              <div class="panel">
                  <p>Chocolate cake jujubes donut pudding. Jujubes gummies soufflé topping chupa chups chocolate cake. Halvah carrot cake icing dragée. Donut caramels lemon drops cupcake. Pudding sugar plum lemon drops sesame snaps icing dessert. Tootsie roll caramels chupa chups marzipan sweet roll wafer. Jelly-o icing lemon drops cake chupa chups marshmallow bear claw. Oat cake bonbon tiramisu bonbon. Chocolate bar tart ice cream macaroon cake dragée gingerbread.</p>              
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
          <div class="large-12">
              <div class="panel">
              <p>Caramels tiramisu liquorice. Chocolate faworki brownie dragée wafer. Lemon drops tart bear claw wafer. Tootsie roll candy canes faworki lollipop bear claw bonbon sesame snaps jelly-o.  Danish sesame snaps toffee lollipop tootsie roll. Macaroon lollipop jelly-o pie gummi bears danish gummies jelly-o gingerbread. Pie croissant jujubes lollipop fruitcake icing. Fruitcake sweet roll cotton candy halvah gummi bears oat cake powder. Danish pudding toffee wypas bonbon macaroon lollipop faworki tiramisu.</p>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
          <div class="large-12">
              <div class="panel">
              <p>Biscuit marshmallow wypas tootsie roll tart candy icing. Halvah faworki danish brownie chocolate cake candy. Carrot cake cotton candy donut lollipop pie oat cake. Sweet toffee pudding soufflé marshmallow donut chocolate bar. Gummi bears gummi bears brownie halvah cookie liquorice biscuit tart. Halvah cupcake tiramisu jelly beans apple pie liquorice fruitcake jelly beans. </p>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
          <div class="large-12">
              <div class="panel">
              <p>Sesame snaps marzipan sugar plum wypas soufflé danish. Candy jelly-o topping biscuit sesame snaps gingerbread chocolate soufflé chupa chups. Jelly marshmallow wypas apple pie candy canes halvah cake. Ice cream biscuit icing jujubes lemon drops. Marshmallow biscuit cotton candy muffin. Bear claw pudding cookie. Soufflé jujubes gummi bears jujubes muffin. Wafer croissant marzipan apple pie tootsie roll jelly beans tootsie roll pudding.</p>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now if you want to have same height for all the images then you can add a class to each of your img say a `grid-img` like so `<img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" class="grid-img">` and then define it as such:

```
.grid-img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Take note that the images may be distorted, will not look good, as they will be stretched to the maximum width of the grid (e.g. 8 columns) and height (e.g. 150 px). This is where image resizing tool comes in handy.